# Only small portion of window visible when shown.  How do I show the whole thing?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe

I have a JFrame full of various components. When I run it, only a small portion appears. I have to resize the window (drag the edge with cursor) to make everything appear. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the pack() method on your frame before making it visible:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
...
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: It doesn't quite "pack" everything. I tried resizing the frame but the content just reorients themselves as I resized the frame. Is there any way I can just make everything "permanent" (like a PDF file) so that no one can resize the window?

Comment: You should post your code if you want better answers. Otherwise all we can do is guess potential solutions, which is a very inefficient way of solving problems.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was I put in f.setVisible(true); before any of the components were made. I just put that line in the end an volla. And next time, I will put in my codes! Thanks again